# How do i install php 5.2 on centos 6?

Tags: php, centos6, php-5.2

I have a managed VPS with Godaddy and currently with PHP 5.6. My question is.

Is it possible to install multiple versions of PHP on centos 6? If so how do I install PHP 5.2?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't. PHP 5.2 is ancient, unsupported, and insecure. If you have old software that won't run on PHP 5.6, upgrade or replace it.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I am partially aware of the issues, but don't really have a choice for the moment.